# Controlling the order of useDynLib lines in NAMESPACE with roxygen2

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I am working on a R package that uses an external 3rd party dll to load data. I have written wrapper functions to that external dll that I can call with `.C()`

Assume that my package is called `mypackage` and the external is called `xternal.dll`. It seems that to load the `mypackage.dll` that is generated during compilation it is necessary that `external.dll` is loaded first. I am using `roxygen2` to manage the `NAMESPACE` file, and I have used the `#' @useDynLib` tags. Unfortunately when `roxygen2` writes the `NAMESPACE` file it adds the `useDynLib` calls in the lexical order of the shared object being called like A-Z, a-z.

Is there a way to control the order of the `useDynLib` in the namespace by `roxygen2`?

So far I have found the follwing solutions and neither of them seems to be particularly compelling:

- Renaming my package to be lexically ordered after the external dll.
- Managing the `NAMESPACE file manually`.

Example:
The function foo.R:

```
#' @export
#' @useDynLib xternal
#' @useDynLib mypackage
foo <- function(){
  return(FALSE)
}
```

results in the `NAMESPACE` after calling `devtools::document()`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(foo)
useDynLib(mypackage)
useDynLib(xternal)
```

The package would fail to load, however if I manually swap the two `useDynLib` lines the package installs and works fine.

Comment: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/6b9582ac56002cd5c990530f603fe1bf987c3bbe/R/namespace.R#L32 is what's causing your frustration and has no conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very helpful hint received on [GitHub](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/821):
The solution is to use the `@rawNamespace` tag, that writes a verbatim line into the `NAMESPACE` file:

foo.R:

```
#' @export
#' @rawNamespace useDynLib(xternal); useDynLib(mypackage)
foo <- function(){
  return(FALSE)
}
```

results in a NAMESPACE file:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(foo)
useDynLib(xternal); useDynLib(mypackage)
```

and the shared objects are loaded in the correct order.